# Packet loss on Channel Handler Context on Netty

Tags: java, netty

The problem: I'm having some packet loss internally. I mean internally because did capture all the traffic with wireshark and confirm the packet arrived at server, but did not arrive at channelRead0 method.

Scenario:
I built a SIP Server using Netty. The system uses UDP to communicate with other sip endpoints and works fine at low load.

My doubt is about design. Since SIP is a session protocol, on every packet received, I need to check what session it belongs to. The heavy workload surely is on the synchronized list that holds all sessions (I know need to optimize this on the future).

The whole system logic is inside channelRead0 method and this probably is the reason i'm losing some packets. The problem start to happens at around 500 pkt/sec.

There is no database connection (yet), the only I/O is writing log to a file which has almost no impact.

The question: How should I proper design this to handle 5000 pkts/sec? Maybe put all packets in a synchronized queue and handle them later?

Thanks for all help

Comment: Double check you packet parsing logic, sometimes, a single Bytebuf you receive may contain multiple SIP packets, and this is a pretty common mistake to make. Since you didn't post any code, I cannot confirm that this is the case for you

Comment: @Ferrybig Good catch, didn't think about this. Can it happen with UDP packets? I taught this only happens on TCP. Thanks